# returning the concatenation of values in a list JS

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I'm trying to write a function that returns the concatenation of the values in the list

For example, if the input was ["blank", "space", "red"], i'd like for it to return "blank space red"

Here's what I have so far. It's blatantly incomplete because I'm kind of stuck

```
function list_concat(x) {
    for (i=0; i<x.length; i++);
```

I'm struggling to move forward because I know how to add strings to one another (concat()) but I'm not sure how to write the loop that would repeatedly do it. I could just use x[0] + " " + x[1] but that would require a definite amount of values.

Comment: use `join`: e.g `['a', 'b'].join(' ')`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [`Array.prototype.join(" ");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

In your specific case:

```
function list_concat(x) {
    return x.join(" ");
}
```